# ThreadStateException c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, thread-safety, thread-state

I have a ThreadStateException that i need to have STAThread...
The problem appeared yesterday, I even ckecked previous versions from my git repo (which were 100% working) - now they're not.

Code for main:

```cs
[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new ClientList());
}
```

And ClientList form method:

```cs
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    [...]
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    DialogResult result = ofd.ShowDialog();
    [...]
}
```

Any idea why STA won't work?

**EDIT:** In new (test) application everything works fine. Only this project throws an exception on OpenFileDialog.

**EDIT 2:** The getAppartmentState shows that app is in MTA from the very first line of Main. Is [STAThread] ignored?

Comment: May help: [A ThreadStateException occures when trying to restart a thread](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13170/471214)

Comment: Fine, but I'm not creating my own Thread. It's main entry of the app and I personally don't know other way to set its apartment than [STAThread]

Comment: Verify or log `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ApartmentState` at the start of the click handler.

Comment: According to "[ThreadStateException Error in openfiledialog](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/180fde7b-ee75-4a6e-bb8e-c56b1552415d/)", adding `thread.SetApartmentState (ApartmentState.STA);` before `OpenFileDalog()` solves.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It's MTA of course.

Comment: @mmdemirbas I can't setApartmentState on a running Thread.

Comment: OK, now try to intercapt it ASAP, ie in Main() and/or in Form_Loadded.

Comment: @HenkHolterman It's MTA right from the very first line of Main. Looks like [STAThread] is ignored.

Comment: Good to know. Even better to state so in the question. Comments don't count.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Any idea why it happens?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [STAThread missing, but it is there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584434/stathread-missing-but-it-is-there)