# ThreadStateException on OpenFileDialog with No Threads

Tags: c#, .net, openfiledialog, microsoft-fakes

So this is an odd one. I have a simple form to do testing on other code. It used to work, but after adding some Fakes assemblies (trying to automate data generation for unit tests), my code halts with a `ThreadStateException` on `ShowDialog`. No multi-threading on my part, didn't even make it to any non-boiler plate code. Searching is not helpful, as the only solution is supposed to be marking with the `STAThread` attribute which is already done. And again, the code used to work fine, no changes in project configuration other than the Fakes.

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Exception happens on `ShowDialog` below.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using(var fod = new OpenFileDialog())
        {
            if(fod.ShowDialog()==System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                runTest(fod.FileName );
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit:
I added a breakpoint in `Main` to check `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState()`, and it is returning MTA, so it appears the `STAThread` attribute is being ignored. I don't think you can change the apartment of a running thread, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: That's not an uncommon mishap.  You need to post the content of your Output window to get help.

Comment: @HansPassant, my Output and Immediate windows are blank, no debug info.

Comment: Found a similar unanswered question as well, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560479/threadstateexception-c-sharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it, it was a fairly dumb project configuration mistake.

I had a project reference to another test project (for the data I needed to populate). For system configuration reasons I'd rather not go into, both of these projects had the same Assembly name. I found this out as I tried to work around issue by creating my own app thread, and then ran into other type load exceptions. I moved the classes around so the assemblies don't have to reference each other.

I have no idea why that caused the main thread to be created as MTA, but it did. Any insight would be appreciated.

For completeness, this was the workaround I didn't need,

```
        var runapp = new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                Application.EnableVisualStyles();
                Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
                Application.Run(new Form1());
            });

        var thread = new System.Threading.Thread(runapp);
        thread.SetApartmentState(System.Threading.ApartmentState.STA);
        thread.Start();
        thread.Join();
```

Comment: @Downvoter, ouch. I know it was a dumb mistake, but does the answer really deserve a downvote?

Comment: I have the same problem, and this solution does not work. Any ideas ?